# VueJS reactivity does not work inside blade section

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I've just been experimenting with vuejs, trying to get it to work on a laravel project on mine.

The problem is that the reactivity works fine if my element is in the layout blade template, but not in the section. Im trying to modify the properties from the console to see them change in the DOM.

I have a view called blog.blade.php, which extends the layout app.blade.php

The code in app.blade.php

```
    <div id='test'>
        @{{ test }}
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app2 = new Vue({
        el : "#test",
        data : {
            test : "Hello World"
        }
    });

    var app3 = new Vue({
        el : "#root",
        data : {
            tester : "Hello Vue!"
        }
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the code in my blog.blade.php view

```
   <div class='card'>
        <div class='card-header'>Post a comment</div>
        <div class='card-body'>
           <div id='root'> @{{ tester }} </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the element root, the value of tester property shows up, but it cannot be modified, but this works in the test element thats at the end of app.blade.php layout file.

Im really lost and have no idea whats going on here.
If anyone can shed some light on this, that'd be great.

https://pastebin.com/GkNqFUzy

Comment: why are you using two vue instances ?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim I was just trying it out lol. It didn't work with a single instance either

Comment: what do want to get ?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahimi im trying the most basic vue example from the video on their website. Initialize a component, render a property in the DOM and modify it from console and have it show up in the DOM. However that is not working.

Comment: how do you modify it using console?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim app3.tester = 'Foobar'

Comment: please provide me the whole code of blog.blade.php in order to test it

Comment: I'll edit my question to provide the link to the code as SO does not allow me to paste it here

Comment: view the source is `{{ tester }}` still on the dom? Or has blade removed it.

Comment: it works fine on my machine i could app3.test="foobar" and the view in dom will be changed

Comment: @LawrenceCherone the property renders fine(i use @{{tester}} in blade). However it just has no reactivity, i modify it from the console and the changes do not reflect.

Comment: Sorry, misread.. Instead of `app3.test="foobar"` use `app2.$data.test = 'foobar';`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone undefined property while using $data

Comment: remove `@section('content')` and `@endsection` and retry

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim why would i do that, i need those in my final render.

Comment: in my case it works when i remove that

Answer (score 1):

**To change value vuejs provides v-model attribute**

Read this [official](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) doc for more info

```
<div class='card'>
    <div class='card-header'>Post a comment</div>
    <div class='card-body'>
       <div id='root' v-model='tester'> @{{ tester }} </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you change tester value in vue dev console or browser console then you can see it being changed easily

I also suggest you to use [Vue Dev Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) to debug vue app.